# Handle orientation of tablet in a c# Windows Forms app

Tags: c#, winforms, orientation, tablet

I am developing a C# windows forms app which needs to work on Windows 8 tablets, and needs to handle orientation changes.  Does anyone have any idea how this could be achieved?

I have looked around for this and it seems possible to detect when a form is loaded what the orientation is, but how does one handle displaying things correctly.

I can't really find much on this.  I am new to developing tablet apps...maybe I am not asking the right question.  At the moment I have been told to make it a Windows Forms app rather than WPF.

Anyone got any ideas?
Jonathan

Comment: Actually I realised I have asked quite a silly question and TableLayoutPanel and FlowLayoutPanel have been provided specifically to provide responsive design. I am new to .net windows development so sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to hook this event and handle it in your code:

```
SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I decided using the flow/table layoutpanels will do what I need.  It seems to work.